# How do I search for a photo with a specific filename using the Google Photos API?

Tags: javascript, google-photos, google-photos-api

When I go to https://photos.google.com/ I can enter a filename into the search box and find the photo with that filename.

Is it possible to do that using the Google Photos API? I can't find any example or reference that shows how to do it.
https://developers.google.com/photos